# Encrypting Text as well as Integers

Tags: encryption, ascii, rsa

Hi i have created an RSA encryption using Java that so far only encrypts and decrypts BigIntegers and would like to make it so that it can also do the same for other characters, i have a feeling that i would have to convert everything into Ascii (if this is even possible) to then encrypt but no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i would have to convert everything into Ascii

consider encryption as converting a byte array to a different byte array (even BigInt is represented as a byte array)

Still I see several issues:

1. You are implementing your own textbook RSA (no padding, no mitigation for side-channel attacks) and this approach is really really not secure. It's ok to do it for learning purposes (even I'd object) , but not for any real life secure encryption.
2. RSA is secure (when used properly) to encrypt a fixed block of data. If you want to use RSA to encrypt data of any length, you may use hybrid encryption (use symmetric encryption with a random key to encrypt data and RSA to encrypt the key)

you may have a look at my blog for that

https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/

Comment: hi there, yes this is just for a uni project ive been given so wont be used in real life not even i have that much faith in myself lol.